# Finding all elements in list based on criteria for instance variable in Groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

For this scenario

```
class A {
    List<B> bList
}

class B {
    Long chainId
}
```

I am trying to get items of type B from an instance of type A if the chainId is present in a chainIdList. When i use

```
a.bList*.find { chainIdList.contains(it.chainId) }
```

I get an error : query did not return a unique result: 4.
It seems to me that instead of groovy method 'find', the Grails GORM method is being invoked so I get all rows (4 at the moment) of type B from database for each of the 2 B elements in A.
Any suggestions/insight?

Comment: I can't make sense of this question.  Is `List B` supposed to be `List bList`?  What is `chainIdList`?

Comment: You are right Jeff. Didn't put that correctly. Edited the code. And  chainIdList is a list of chainIds I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling find on every element in the list, not on the list itself

Remove the `*`, I.e.

```
a.bList.find { chainIdList.contains(it.chainId) }
```

Or to find all matching elements

```
a.bList.findAll { chainIdList.contains(it.chainId) }
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. Makes perfect sense. But when i try this i only get one item from the bList. chainIdList as two ids and there are corresponding objects (2) in bList. Not sure why I can't fetch both.

Comment: `find` returns the first match. If you need all matches then use `findAll` instead of `find` @AnupTripathi